# How to monitor VSTS agent availability using PowerShell?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

How to get vsts agent status from a remote agent machine using powershell?
I did google search and i didn't find any ideas or information about this.

I found solution in c#. But i am unable to do this in powershell. I tried to call the c# code in powershell. I am getting the error

**Add-Type : (0) : Metadata file 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=15.0.0.0.dll' could not be found
(1) : using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;**

My code that is throwing the error is

$Assemblies = ("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=15.0.0.0",
                "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Lab.Client, Version=15.0.0.0")

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a coding service. What have you tried? Where did you fail? Take a look at [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference your `.dll` file by path:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\path\to\your\assembly.dll'
```

Keep in mind that as `-Path` accepts array of strings ([see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-6)) you can use it like this:

```
$assemblies = "C:\Path\To\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll", "C:\Path\To\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Lab.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path $assemblies
```

Edit: as it's been spotted (in the comments - credits to [user3081672](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3081672/user3081672)), alternative method is to run

```
TestControllerConfig.exe status
```

This will give you status of all the agents on the controller. Check example [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/allendm/2013/11/20/getting-the-status-of-your-test-agents/).

Comment: I found an alternative way to get the agents status(ready or not) with out connecting using TFS assemblies.
We can do that by running process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TestControllerConfig.exe" with parameter as "Status".

This will give you the information about all agent machines registered under that controller

Comment: Hi @user3081672 - I added your solution to my answer. Please mark it as accepted if you find it useful. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah.. Thank you Robdy